# Java Web - How can I make the Session to not stop?

Tags: java, web, java-ee-7

My problem is that I log in into my Java Web Application which works fine and after going on another site on it the "jsessionid" disappears and I do have to log in again. What can I do to stay logged in?

```
@ManagedBean
public class SecurityBean {
    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String template;

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }
    public boolean isLoggedIn(){
        return loggedIn;
    }
    public void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedIn){
        this.loggedIn = loggedIn;
    }
    public String getTemplate(){
        if(loggedIn){
            return "/WEB-INF/templates/user.xhtml";
        }else{
            return "/WEB-INF/templates/main.xhtml";
        }
    }
    public void setTemplate(String template){
        this.template = template;
    }

    public String login(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try{
            request.login(username, password);
        }catch(ServletException e){
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Login failed"));
            return "error";
        }
        loggedIn = true;
        return "user/home"
    }

    public void logout(){
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        try{
            request.logout();
            loggedIn = false;
        }catch(ServletException e){
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Logout failed"));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Save whatever information you need in a cookie.

Comment: it already is :(

Comment: what application server are you using ? What are you using for login into the application ?